# Active class on page load not triggering

Tags: javascript, html

So I have an image slider on a website with navigational dots that have an active animation if the background image is on the current dot. I have set it up so that when the page loads the first dot will have the active class from the start. Everything is working well but I just do not understand why the active dot on page load won't trigger unless I include the `onload = buttonClick()` on the body element, I have tried using an event listener in JS but it does not work. This does not make sense to me as my head class has an active listener that calls my onStart function, which in turn, should call my `buttonClick` function and activate the active class. Can someone help shed some light on this problem? It just does not make sense to me. thnx ^_^

**HTML**:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head id = "start">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Ukiyo Sushi ツ</title>
        <link href = "style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src = "/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> <!--<body onload = "buttonClick()">--> 
        <header id = "bg">
            <nav class = "navbar">
                <a href = "#" class = "logo">Ukiyo Sushi ツ</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href ="#" class = "about">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#" class = "menu">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#" class = "services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#" class = "contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav> 
            <div class = "sushiPlatter">
                <h2 id = "caption">Chef's Special Sushi Platter</h2>
                <div class = "dots">
                    <span class = "dot" onclick = "imgslider(1); currentSlide(1);"></span>
                    <span class = "dot" onclick = "imgslider(2); currentSlide(2);"></span>                    <span class = "dot" onclick = "imgslider(3); currentSlide(3);"></span>
                </div>
                <a href = "#">View Menu</a>
            </div>
            </header>
        <section class = "description">
            <div class = "topRow">
                <dl class = "adress">420 High Street, Houston, Texas 77075</dl>
                <dl class = "phoneNumber">(832)-123-4567</dl>
                <dt>Lunch: </dt>
                <dl class = "hours">12:00pm - 4:00pm</dl>
                <dt>Dinner: </dt>
                <dl class = "hours">6:00pm - 10:30pm</dl>
            </div>   
            <div class = "imageDiv">
                <span>Welcome to Ukiyo Sushi ^_^</span>
                <figure>
                    <img src = "img/lantern.jpg" class = "descImg">
                    <figcaption  class = "imgCap">Ukiyo Sushi is a japanese sushi restaurant that was established in Houston, Texas in 2010. Due to our excellent customer service and quality of food, we have built a reputation as one of the best sushi restauraunts in the greater Houston area. </figcaption  class = "imgCap">
                </figure>
            </div> 
        </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
    var imageIndex = 1;
    document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("load", onStart);

    function onStart(){
       buttonClick(imageIndex);
    }

    function currentSlide(n)
    {
       buttonClick(imageIndex = n);
    }

    function buttonClick(n){
       var i;
       var dot = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
       if(n > dot.length){ imageIndex = 1}
       if(n < 1){imageIndex = dot.length}
       for(i = 0; i < dot.length; i++){       
          dot[i].classList.remove("active");
       }
       dot[imageIndex -1].className += " active";
    }
```

EDIT: alright so I figured out you cannot use the head element for events, and that solved my first problem but now I cannot trigger the onload event with an event listener I have to use the onload event in my `HTML` does anybody know why?

**HTML**:

```html
    <body> <!--<body onload = "onStart()">-->
        <header id = "bg">
            <nav class = "navbar">
                <a href = "#" class = "logo">Ukiyo Sushi ツ</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href ="#" class = "about">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#" class = "menu">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#" class = "services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#" class = "contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav> 
            <div class = "sushiPlatter">
                <h2 id = "caption">Chef's Special Sushi Platter</h2>
                <div class = "dots">
                    <span class = "dot" onclick = "imgslider(1); currentSlide(1);"></span>
                    <span class = "dot" onclick = "imgslider(2); currentSlide(2);"></span>                    <span class = "dot" onclick = "imgslider(3); currentSlide(3);"></span>
                </div>
                <a href = "#">View Menu</a>
            </div>
            </header>
        <section class = "description">
            <div class = "topRow">
                <dl class = "adress">420 High Street, Houston, Texas 77075</dl>
                <dl class = "phoneNumber">(832)-123-4567</dl>
                <dt>Lunch: </dt>
                <dl class = "hours">12:00pm - 4:00pm</dl>
                <dt>Dinner: </dt>
                <dl class = "hours">6:00pm - 10:30pm</dl>
            </div>   
            <div class = "imageDiv">
                <span>Welcome to Ukiyo Sushi ^_^</span>
                <figure>
                    <img src = "img/lantern.jpg" class = "descImg">
                    <figcaption  class = "imgCap">Ukiyo Sushi is a japanese sushi restaurant that was established in Houston, Texas in 2010. Due to our excellent customer service and quality of food, we have built a reputation as one of the best sushi restauraunts in the greater Houston area. </figcaption  class = "imgCap">
                </figure>
            </div> 
        </section>
    </body>
var imageIndex = 1;
document.body.addEventListener("load", onStart);

function onStart(){
   buttonClick(imageIndex);
}

function currentSlide(n)
{
   buttonClick(imageIndex = n);
}

function buttonClick(n){
   var i;
   var dot = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
   if(n > dot.length){ imageIndex = 1}
   if(n < 1){imageIndex = dot.length}
   for(i = 0; i < dot.length; i++){       /*removes the active class for the whole dot class*/
      dot[i].classList.remove("active");
   }
   dot[imageIndex -1].className += " active";
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
    var imageIndex = 1;
    document.body.addEventListener("load", onStart);

    function onStart(){
       buttonClick(imageIndex);
    }

    function currentSlide(n)
    {
       buttonClick(imageIndex = n);
    }

    function buttonClick(n){
       var i;
       var dot = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
       if(n > dot.length){ imageIndex = 1}
       if(n < 1){imageIndex = dot.length}
       for(i = 0; i < dot.length; i++){       /*removes the active class for the whole dot class*/
          dot[i].classList.remove("active");
       }
       dot[imageIndex -1].className += " active";
    }
```

Comment: remove `()` from the function name in `onload`.

Comment: if you put `()` then the `onload` function will call the returned value of the function and its undefined in your case.

Comment: No that's not what I am asking I want to know why do I have to include the onload event because my head element has an event listener that activates my onStart function which should trigger the buttonClick function. Like shouldnt the onStart function trigger the first active class without me needing to use the onload event for buttonClick since onStart calls buttonClick

Comment: `head` element doesn't fire `onload` event, listen on `document.body` instead.

Comment: @Teemu That did not work it is still is the same as before why does the active class on load only trigger when i use the buttonclick on load event shouldn't the onstart function do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Looked around a bit a tested it out and it works, instead of using an event listener on the body I just put one on the window itself and it works. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Solution:

```
var imageIndex = 1;
window.addEventListener("load", onStart);

function onStart(){
   buttonClick(imageIndex);
}

function currentSlide(n)
{
   buttonClick(imageIndex = n);
}

function buttonClick(n){
   var i;
   var dot = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
   if(n > dot.length){ imageIndex = 1}
   if(n < 1){imageIndex = dot.length}
   for(i = 0; i < dot.length; i++){       /*removes the active class for the whole dot class*/
      dot[i].classList.remove("active");
   }
   dot[imageIndex -1].className += " active";
}
```